# R: Testing the null hypothesis of zero skew

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I need to test the null hypothesis that my steady returns have a zero skewness with a confidence level of 95%. Do you have any ideas which formula I can take for this kind of test ? I tried the Agostino test for skewness, but think it's not the best way, because I can't set a confidence level.

```
library(moments)
?agostino.test
```

Comment: Your difficulty appears to arise from a misunderstand of how hypothesis tests work. Confidence levels are for confidence intervals. You choose a significance level for a hypothesis test. The D'Agostino test implemented in the R package `moments` returns a p-value, with which it is easy to do a hypothesis test at any desired significance level. (On the other hand, it's not at all clear what value there would be in performing hypothesis tests of skewness of returns - I suspect that would be of almost no use at all - but that's another issue: returns are going to be skew, even if only a little)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could have a look on pastecs package and stat.desc function.

```
library(pastecs)
stat.desc(iris$Sepal.Length, norm=TRUE)
```

Comment: What is this function? How does it work / how does it test skewness? Note that we aren't an R tech support site. Questions that just ask for code suggestions are off topic because they aren't real statistics questions. By the same token, this isn't a real answer by our standards. Can you edit this to add some substance?